# android - assets files path

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have problem with assets files path in android studio. I want give path of text file in assets folder like below:

```
File f = new File(path_of_text_file_in_assets);
fw = new FileWriter(f);
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

I have similar problem in other parts of this code, that I want give the path of images in subfolder of assets like below:

```
File ff = new File(path_of_image_in_subfolder_of_assets);
StringBuilder sbFeatureX = uniformQuantization( ff );
```

I have searched a lot on the internet, but no answer!!

Note: please consider I don't want open the file, so the `getAssets().open()` is not my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the File class for files in assets. File is for files in the file system.

The only way to handle assets files is indeed with that .open() function using the input stream.

Further you cannot write to files in assets. They are read only there.

FileWriter and FileReader both cannot be used.

Comment: so what should I do about this? How can I solve this problem??

Comment: You did not tell which problem you have. You only told that you did not want to use an input stream. Much has not been said. Tell what you want to do.

Comment: absolutely you are right :), I work on image retrieval project. in part of code I want to give text file to fileWriter and then to buffer, because file modifies in buffer (some feature of database's images (image in assets) is writting in that file in buffer). for this purpose I have to give address of each image in database to uniformQuantization(); for some processing. my problem is: how give address to these methods???