# Read file from Android Assets with FileReader

Tags: java, android, file, assets, filereader

I'm trying to read a files from assets but it is neither reading the file nor throwing the exception. I'm working on an OCR system, that reads the word or sentence and extract the names from it by comparing the words or group of alphabets with the ArrayList made from that "names.txt" file. Names are about 15000, each name is stored in seperate/single line. Actually, I'm adding these names to the ArrayList to find out if particular name exists in that file. Everything is done and tested, the only thing that is left is reading the file. I've tried the same code with java IDE that reads the files from drive and it's working on Java ide but not in Android Studio.
Tried piece of code:

```
FileReader freader = new FileReader("file:///android_asset/names.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(freader);
```

I've also tried,

```
FileReader freader = new FileReader(getAssets().open("names.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(freader);
```

gives the error

```
Error:(1387, 26) error: no suitable constructor found for FileReader(InputStream)
constructor FileReader.FileReader(File) is not applicable (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to File)
constructor FileReader.FileReader(FileDescriptor) is not applicable (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to FileDescriptor)
constructor FileReader.FileReader(String) is not applicable (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to String)"
```

And also this:

```
FileReader freader = new FileReader(context.getAssets().open("names.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(freader);
```

That says "cannot resolve symbol 'context' "

The path of the file is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISGVv.png).

Comment: Is the goal just to find out how to use `FileReader` or would you accept any solution that reads the asset file?

Comment: `The path of the file is ` That is the path on your development pc. Such a path has nothing to do with the file system on your android device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648385/android-assets-files-path/50654393?noredirect=1#comment88325238_50654393

Comment: @Barns Thanks for your response, I definitely need and accept the solution, That's what i'm trying to get, possible solution or the code that solves my problem

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for?  Just a `String` containing the content of the file?

Comment: @Barns Actually, the file contains the names, I'm adding these names to the ArrayList to find out if particular name exists in that file.

Comment: There can be many solutions to this problem. How many names in the list? How are the names stored in the file (csv?, one name per line?). Do you wish to make several searches while the app is open?  Or just one search and done? Do you need to insert new names in the list?

Comment: Names are about 15000, stored in txt file, each name is stored in single line.
I'm working on an OCR system, that reads the word or sentence and extract the names from it by comparing the words or group of alphabets with the ArrayList made from that names.txt file. Everything is done and tested, the only thing that is left is reading the file.
I've tried the same code with java IDE that reads the files from drive and it's working on Java ide but not in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `FileReader`. Use a `BufferedReader` wrapped around an `InputStreamReader` wrapped around the `InputStream` you already got from `getAssets().open()`.

Comment: I've tried your piece but it's also not working. 
Error: incompatible types: InputStream cannot be converted to Reader What to do next?

Answer (score -1):

FileReader needs a file system path.

There is no constructor for an input stream.

So no you cannot use FileReader to 'read' files from assets.

Copy the file from assets to the file system.

After that use that file on file system.

If you dont insist in using FileReader you could change

```
FileReader freader = new FileReader(getAssets().open("names.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(freader);
```

to

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("images/names.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
```

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your time and response, Can you please sort out and provide me the solution/code that can fix my problem?
If FileReader can't be used to read the files, what else can be helpful?

Comment: I already told you what you have to do to fix your problem. And you then can use FileReader. I wonder why that is not clear. As long as you stick to using FileReader thats what you have to do. And you never told why you want to use FileReader.

Comment: Have a look again on the description, I've updated and improved the explanation. Hope it'll give you the better explanation of the problem.

Comment: The constructor `BufferedReader(InputStream in)` doesn't exist either.

Comment: My god... What a great chance to post an answer! @EJP.

Comment: What a great chance to fix your own, you mean. Any time you're ready. You can't seriously wish to pretend you're the only person who has ever thought of a correct answer to this in the last 22 years.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks again for better explanation of your answer,
I've tried your piece but it's also not working. 
Error: incompatible types: InputStream cannot be converted to Reader

What to do next?

Comment: Did you use the InputStreamReader (which i forgot and was mentioned by EJP so kindly) too? It should compile. Your compile time message is strange. Please post your code. In your post! You are not casting are you?

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));`